# Cannot assign calculated value to user field in Rules

Tags: 7, rules

Here is the situation and what I want to do:

- Users have a "days left" field of type integer.
- A user will set a date range while creating a "time off" content type.
- When he hits the save button, a rule will intercept, subtract the date range from his "days left" field and save the result as the new "days left" value.

here is what I have done:

- user clicks save button rule intercepts
- action - gets the duration and divides it by 86400 (to convert it to days from seconds)
- action - converts the result to integer
- action - subtracts the converted value
  from content authors "days left" field.

At this point I want to assign the result of the subtraction to the author's "days left" field. The node:author:field-days-left variable is available and I select it. But the result of the subtraction is not.

I also tried to convert the result of the subtraction to integer and then assign it, but it did not work too.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out why the result variable was not available; my solution was to change the order of the actions to:

After the user clicks save button, rule intercepts:

- get the value of author's "days left" field and multiply with 86400 (convert days to seconds)
- get the duration of content and subtract it from the previous value
- divide the result by 86400 (convert it back to days from seconds)
- convert the result to integer
- subtract one from this result (this turned out to be necessary, perhaps because of the rounding off during the type conversion)
- assign the result to content author's "days left" field.

I do not like having to make two type conversions but this is a working solution.